# Point to a hashSet java

Tags: java, pointers, hashset

How would I write an if statement that says: if pos2[targetPos3] doesn't point to a hashset (is not a hashset) ? I tried that but it still gives me a null point exception.

```
Object[] pos2;
int targetPos3;
targetPos3 = word.charAt(2) - 'a';

if(pos2[targetPos3] != (HashSet<String>) pos2[targetPos3]){
   System.out.println("Sorry");
 }
```

Comment: Check for null using `pos2[index] == null` and use `instanceof` to check for type if not null. Why are you storing them in `Object[]` anyway ?

Comment: [SSCCE please](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @DeepakBala, you do not need to check that `pos2[idx]` is null when checking for `instanceof` is is null then can not be a instance of naturally.

Comment: @Vash while you're right, it does not invalidate the comment. No one knows that the OP is trying to do. `targetPos3 = word.charAt(2) - 'a';` does not make sense. What is `word` ? What is this snippet even supposed to do !?

Comment: @DeepakBala, I was just referring that, validating null before a instance check is redundant (and also recognized as bad practice). The snipes, IMHO present the problem that was highly recognized looking on the answers. what `word` is and the logic of code is quite irrelevant at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!(pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet)){
    System.out.println("Sorry");
}
```

There is no way to see if it's a `HashSet` of `String` (or any other type for that matter) because of [*type erasure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/339699/335858).

Answer (score 1):

The `instanceof` operator will help you here.  It can tell you if the object is a `HashSet`, but due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), here at runtime, you won't be able to tell if it's a `HashSet<String>`, just if it's a `HashSet`.

```
if (!(pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**instanceof operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) in Java.

```
if (!(pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet)) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` is the operator you're looking for:

```
if(! pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet){
    System.out.println("Sorry");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `instanceof`. For example:

```
if(pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet) {
    ...
}
```

However you also need to instantiate your array and do bounds checking. So:

```
pos2 = new Object[desiredLength];

if((targetPos3 < pos2.length) && (pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't do any error checking.

```
if(targetPos3 < pos2.length){   
   if(!(pos2[targetPos3] instanceof HashSet)){
      System.out.println("Sorry");
   }
}
```

Check also for `word != null`.
What you need is `instanceof` operator to verify is you actually have a `HashSet`